# Open a new tab automatically in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a project where i need the browser to automatically open a new tab in the user's browser after a click on the website (i know that ethnically that might be wrong, but i am trying this for an ad, just to be clear).

this is my code so far:

```
var body = jQuery('body');

body.append('<a href="<?php echo $redirect ?>" id="ezPopUnder" target="_blank"></a>');

var ad_span = jQuery('#ezPopUnder');
ad_span.css('display', 'none');

var clicked  = 0;
var scrolled = 0;

body.on('click touchend', function(e) {
    if(clicked === 1 || scrolled === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    clicked = 1;

    ad_span.trigger("click");
});

ad_span.click(function(e) {
    var win = window.open(ad_span.attr('href'), '_blank');
    win.focus();
});

window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    scrolled = 1;
};
```

When i am trying this on Android it works fine (on the native browser and chrome) but when i run this on iOS, no matter what browser, i am encountering an issue which the browser notifies the user that the page is about to load a pop-up.

I looked through Stack Overflow for an answer and there were some answers but non of them actually worked.
Is there a way to disable the pop-up alert for iOS browsers using JavaScript or JQuery?

I know that the pop-up alert is a safety percussion and if you have moral problems with my request it's fine, but please spare me the moral preach.

Comment: Short answer, no unless you enable it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately It's impossible to avoid this protection with Javascript, because that has been created against scripts like you do.

One way to do it is manually disabling this safety in browser.